# python script in user data not running when ec2 instance boots up

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to do some object detection by running a custom detection script on aws ec2. I have added the user data script as follows for the instance

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/sh
cd /home/ubuntu/path/to/script
sudo python3 strawberry_count_new.py
```

However, when my lambda function copies the image to the instance, the script doess not perform detection. Im not getting any output. When I check my running processes, the python script is running. Im not sure why its not processing the input image coming from the s3. When I run the same script inside the instance, it processes the same input image.

Comment: Generally We forget that user's scripts run from the root user. Are you using root user for same ?

Comment: @Nirmal How do i check if I am using root user or not?

Answer (score 0):

To check the output of your script, and in this case, it's a good practice that you put the sufficient logging in the script, you can redirect the user-data output to a specific path and later go check this output file, this would be done including the following line as your script's first line:

```
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data-aux.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
```

Later you can verify what's happening.

Comment: Doesnt the output already get logged in cloud-init-output.log? Does this create a different kind of log?

Comment: This would only register the output of the commands in the user-data script with no extra info like those appearing in cloud-init-output.log, but you can check cloud-init-output.log too and see what's happening.

Comment: Does the python script run in the background? Does it need permissions to access files in the instance if I start the script using user data?

Comment: Exactly, the user-data script is practically a normal script but it's automatically run once the machine is up and running, nothing special about it. So, yes, you need to guarantee that the tasks running in the script got the required permissions to access X files. But I think you should not have permissions problems as the default user the user-data runs with is root.

Comment: I see that you're using sudo in the script, you shouldn't, as it's the root user running the script.